# AttributeError when calling class2 within class1, class1 has no __init__ attribute

Tags: python, class, init

I'm new to OOP and am trying to use two classes. I'm trying to feed an attribute that isn't created until `Class1` is run to `Class2`, but I'm getting an AttributeError when I run `Class1`.

```
class Class1():
    #some code....

    def function1():
        x=5
        number=2
        test=class2(x)

        answer=Class2.function2(Class2,number)
        print(answer)    

class Class2():
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y=y

    def function2(self, z):
        calculated_answer=self.y+z
        return calculated_answer

    #several more functions that also use y
```

I'm trying to avoid repetition of defining `y` as `x` in every new function in `Class2`, so I thought I could just run `Class2` with `x` and then use `function2` with number to print `7`. Instead I get: `AttributeError: type object 'Class2' has no attribute 'y'`.

Originally I thought I was misunderstanding `__init__`, so I ran this code to make sure:

```
class Class2():
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y=y

    def function2(self, z):
        calculated_answer=self.y+z
        return calculated_answer

x=5
test=class2(x)
```

But this works fine when I type `test.function2(2)` into the shell, returning `7` as expected.

I think I must be misunderstanding how to use `Class2`, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

How do I get rid of this error without just defining `x` in every function in `Class2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to understand your code but one obvious mistake is at this line.

```
 answer=Class2.function2(Class2,number)
```

Change it to

```
 answer = test.function2(number)
```

When you create object by calling it with required init argument, you don't need to pass self parameter while calling functions of the class. It is automatically passed.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try to be clearer next time. Thank you so much, that's exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this line:

```
answer = Class2.function2(Class2, number)
```

First, we must note that the following are equivalent:

```
class A:

    def method(self):
        pass

A().method()
A.method(A())
```

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
class2 = Class2()
answer = class2.function2(number)
```

If we perform the above conversion, that would be the same as this:

```
answer = Class2.function2(Class2(), number)
```

Note that your original code is missing `()` after `Class2`, which means that instead of passing an *instance of `Class2`* to the method, you are passing the *type object* `Class2` itself, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you again for teaching me something! I wish I could accept your answer as well as Rahul's.